# Depth First Search to Solve Random Maze

Tags: java

I tried writing a maze solution method using DFS to find a path through a maze that's generated. But I'm having trouble with it. It doesn't even look like it ever finishes the traversal. Here is some output from a sample run. The maze looks like this:

```
+  +--+--+--+
|  |        |
+  +--+  +  +
|        |  |
+--+--+--+  +
|     |     |
+  +  +  +--+
|  |        |
+--+--+--+  +
```

And my DFS method produces this:

```
0 1 5 9
```

In the end, I want to display that same maze but with numbers inside of it's path that represent the order which I have visited and ran through it.

Anyway, here's my code:

```
public static void depthFirstSearch(){
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[totalCells]; // marks which vertices have been visited during the search
    Stack<Vertex> st = new Stack<Vertex>();
    st.push(graph[0][0]);
    while(!st.isEmpty()){
        Vertex v = st.pop();
        if(!visited[v.label]){
            visited[v.label] = true;
            System.out.print(v.label + " ");
            // auxiliary stack to visit neighbors in the order which they appear
            Stack<Vertex> auxStack = new Stack<Vertex>();
            for(Vertex w : v.neighbors){
                if(!visited[w.label]){
                    auxStack.push(w);
                }
            }
            while(!auxStack.isEmpty()){
                st.push(auxStack.pop());
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here is also the Vertex:

```
class Vertex{
    int label;
    int x;
    int y;
    boolean isVisited = false;
    boolean hasNorthWall = true;
    boolean hasSouthWall = true;
    boolean hasEastWall = true;
    boolean hasWestWall = true;
    boolean hasAllWalls = true;
    ArrayList<Vertex> neighbors = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    public Vertex(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

And my constructor:

```
public Maze(int size) 
{
    this.SIZE = size;
    totalCells = SIZE * SIZE;
    cellStack = new Stack<Vertex>();
    graph = new Vertex[SIZE][SIZE];
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

EDIT: Adding how neighbors are assigned.

```
public void assignNeighbors(Vertex v)
{
    //This handles the cell north of current cell
    if(v.y != 0)
    {
        v.neighbors.add(graph[v.x][v.y-1]);
    }

    //This handles the cell south of the current cell
    if(v.y != (SIZE-1))
    {
        v.neighbors.add(graph[v.x][v.y+1]);
    }

    //This handles the cell left of the current cell
    if(v.x != 0)
    {
        v.neighbors.add(graph[v.x -1][v.y]);
    }

    //right of the current
    if(v.x != SIZE-1)
    {
        v.neighbors.add(graph[v.x + 1][v.y]);
    }
}
```

EDIT2: Adding in how the label is assigned (it just stores the vertex number)

```
public void fill()
{
    int vertexNumber = 0;

    //This loop creates a new vertex
    for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            Vertex v = new Vertex(j,i);
            graph[j][i] = v;
        }
    }

    //adds values to vertex
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            graph[j][i].label = vertexNumber;
            vertexNumber++;
        }
    }

    //This loop assigns the neighbors
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            assignNeighbors(graph[j][i]);
        }
    }
    mazeGenerator();
}
```

Comment: How are you setting up the `neighbors` list?  Your traversal is dependent on this, so make sure that this is correct.

Comment: I just added the source for it. I'm pretty sure it's right since I can print out the full maze on its own.

Comment: How do you generate the `label`?  Given that your visited logic is dependent on that, it'd be good to verify that it's correct.  Likewise for assigning neighbors.  Given what you've posted, it seems likely the issue is somewhere in your parsing/setup logic rather than your actual DFS traversal.

Comment: @BrentNash I added in the method with the label assignment. Hmm, I've been pretty sure that it was my DFS and I wanted to post just the bare minimum so that peoples eyes wouldn't bleed from the wall of text, so that's the reason behind not including more. But if you let me know what else is needed for the issue to be pinpointed, I can add more.

Comment: How does your traversal handle the maze?  It looks like you're visiting all neighbors.  Does mazeGenerator() remove items from neighbors?

Comment: use a breadth-first search so you can find the shortest path

Comment: @MattTimmermans you're assuming he wants to find the shortest path ;-)

Comment: @jdigital mazeGenerator removes walls to create the maze.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I have to use DFS.

Comment: you'll need to show the logic that creates and removes the walls.  before you do that, can you double check to make sure it looks correct?

Comment: based on your output, it looks like there's a wall between 8 and 9.

Comment: @jdigital Hmm it seems like the removeWall method does go through and remove it in terms of debugging... I can look into it some more though. So basically, I'm not constructing the maze properly? Cause I mean, what I'm printing clearly has a visible solution though.

Comment: Your posted code doesn't have any obvious flaws, so it seems likely the issue is somewhere else.  Try printing out the vertices you're pushing onto the stack.  Does 8 ever get pushed?  If not, why not?

Comment: @jdigital One issue is that I'm generating random mazes, so the output isn't the same each time I run. Here's one other issue I noticed though (it's in the depthFirstSearch method): in the for loop v.neighbors, v does not have any neighbors, so it never executes. But I'm not sure why.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to walk thru the code?  This would be the best approach to help identify the problem.  Regarding the random maze: for debugging, you might find it useful to modify things so that the maze is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about this part

```java
for(Vertex w : v.neighbors){
    if(!visited[w.label]){
        auxStack.push(w);
    }
}
while(!auxStack.isEmpty()){
    st.push(auxStack.pop());
}
```

If I'm correct you can replace this with just one loop but this shouldn't be the problem. Have you tried debugging it step by step? You know how the maze looks like and thus you know how the alghoritm should behave in every step. I suggest you try it and then maybe update your post and describe at which step your algorithm behaves weird.

I wanted to add this as comment but I lack the reputation.